# How receive more than a body data from post on server

Tags: spring, post, fetch

I'm trying to send from my client to my server  a new User + a verification Id with this code

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/student', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"email":email, "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName,
            "idToken": idToken}),
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
        }).then(response => { return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

and the method on my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private User createStudent(@RequestBody User user) {
    user.setId(null);
    user.setUserType(UserType.STUDENT);
    //verify the user and create custom role
    return userService.save(user);
}
```

the problem is that I can't access the verify token with user.idToken because idToken is not a User attribute so, how can I receive the body with user attributes and the idToken  separately?

Comment: Create a `Dto` with all the datas you need and return it.

Comment: I'm not used to DTO, do you mean that I create a new class, for example UserDTO with every user attribute + idToken, and then with userDTO create my User + use the idToken?

Comment: For example, but you can also create a class that extends your `User` class and add your `idToken` attribute. Or a `Dto` with a `User` and a `idToken` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that extends your `User` class :

```
public class UserDto extends User {

    private String idToken;

    // getter / setter
}
```

Thus, you can pass this object to your method :

```
private User createStudent(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
    // user.getIdToken(); available
}
```

You can change the return type to `UserDto` if you need to return the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can opt one of the following approaches:

1. Consider extending the `User` class to something like
   `UserWithToken` which will contain all the properties from the
   `User` class and also the `idToken`.
2. Another approach could be using `QueryParam` and pass it in the URL.
   Ex: `/student?idToken=your-token-id`.